# Error on EL Capitan Installation This copy of the Install OS X El Capitan application can't be verified. It may have been corrupted or tampered

Tags: mac, macos, mac-mini, bootable-disk

I have created bootable pendrive using https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201372
I am trying to dump ELCapitan on my mac.
but it throwing error

> This copy of the Install OS X El Capitan application can't be
> verified. It may have been corrupted or tampered with during
> downloading

[image]

What i tried :
**Setting date in terminal "date 0202020216", date 0101010116,  ntpdate -u time.apple.com
all didnot works.**

P.S.

1. my ELCapitan .dmg is correct & downloaded from official Apple site.
2. `hdiutil verify /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg` shows verified OS.

Comment: Did you download it from https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206886 ?

Comment: @Ihf yes dude..

Comment: When that happens I just set the date in System Preferences back a couple of years and turn off set date and time automatically.

Comment: The date issues should all have been fixed earlier this year. I'd try re-downloading using a different connection, or at minimum after rebooting the one you're on; the error doesn't suggest a date issue, but an actual corrupted download.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks ) But i have downloaded .dmg from Apple host only. I don't why it's throwing error. & i also verified with `hdiutil verify /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg` which is verified.

Comment: RE: "I am trying to dump ELCapitan on my mac." -- What exactly do you mean by "dump"? Do you mean "install"? If you are getting the error as shown in the image in your OP, then try the following after having booted from the **USB Installer**... Before starting the install, disconnect from the Internet, open **Terminal** from the **Utilities** _menu_ and use the following command: `date 102300019` Close **Terminal** and then try installing. Do you still get the same error?

Comment: Why 2019 date any reason? @user3439894

Comment: I could successfully install "El Capitan" a few days ago on an old Mac by setting the date to *Jan 1st 12:45 2017* like this `date 0115124517`. A few tips: 1) Make sure that your Mac can't connect to the Internet (turn Wi-Fi off/unplug the Ethernet cable), otherwise it will correct the date. 2) Set the date on your current OS X installation, that is, **before** booting from the USB installer. If that's not possible, in the "Install OS X" routine, launch Utilities>Terminal, set the date, quit Terminal, restart and try again. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/394758/32815 for details.

Comment: @jaume i tried that date didn't work..