# Mac OS X ElCaptain error and now whenever I startup it always directo to OS elcaptain installer

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, high-sierra, startup

so I tried upgrading my Lion os to High sierra and I saw one video on youtube saying that I need to download the El captain in order to update my Macbook Air 2012. After downloading, the installer started to crash and it says that "No packages were eligible for install." I decided to quit the installer but it asked me for a startup disk however there was no option for me to choose from. So whenever I try to restart it, it directly leads me to the installer not allowing me to be back at my screen. Please help me how to fix this thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Does this answer your question? [Mac stuck in "El Capitan" installer loop: "no packages were eligible for install"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/394259/mac-stuck-in-el-capitan-installer-loop-no-packages-were-eligible-for-install)

Comment: Thank you! I tried the solution, unfortunately, it still does not work for me but thank you for redirecting me to the link!