# Reinstalling OS X on a Macbook Pro 8,1 (Early 2011) from Linux without Internet Recovery

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, install, dmg

I've been finding a way to reinstall OS X (or macOS) on the Macbook Pro 8,1 that I've been using. The Macbook has been wiped out to install only Windows 7, and then wiped out again to install Linux. Now, we're in a situation where we need to restore it to its original OS, namely OS X. How do I accomplish this without accessing another OS X machine? I've searched throughout the Internet, maybe I didn't researched enough but it has been almost a month since, and only found handfuls of tutorial which I can't do since they need that I download the installer first and then extract it. I tried Internet Recovery but it asks for an Apple ID, which I assume is the original since I've made one and used that but its no use.
I have downloaded a `InstallMacOSX.dmg` from the [apple website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210717). I don't know how I should continue from here.

I've tried using dmg2img, which simply converts the .dmg to another format, I've looked into the file contents and there seems to be no bootable folder, e.g. a `/boot` directory or something. I've tried booting it from GRUB but no good, and I heard that I should use `dd` to put it on a usb but I've heard that it may render it unusable, (i.e. can't be formatted again) so I'm trying to be cautious in this route.

Downloading another version is quite time extensive, so I'd prefer if I could use the existing `.dmg` file I've already have in store. But if there's no choice I'm open to download another installer image.

Thank you very much, please tell me I've got something wrong.

Comment: Just create an Apple ID.  Even if it’s a new ID it will allow you to download the installer so you can recover your Mac.

Comment: I think the reason it can't be downloaded anymore, it shows an error (I forgot, specifically), because the Macbook has OS X Lion as the original version to download and it doesn't exist in the appstore anymore. Anyways, thank you for your response :).

Comment: Press `Cmd-Opt-R` to install the latest version compatible with your Mac.  In this case, El Capitan.  See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904

Comment: I don't think that's possible in my case since: ``macOS Recovery exceptions
. . .

(1)  If macOS Sierra 10.12.4 or later has never been installed on this Mac, Option-Command-R installs the macOS that came with your Mac, or the closest version still available. And Shift-Option-Command-R isn't available.

  (2) If you erased your entire disk instead of just the startup volume on that disk, macOS Recovery might offer only the macOS that came with your Mac, or the closest version still available. You can upgrade to a later version afterward.``

Comment: That means you might get Yosemite or Mavericks to start.  Did you try?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. The constraints ("without Internet Recovery", "without accessing another OS X machine") your are putting make it quite difficult to achieve your goal. In your case, there are two supported ways of installing macOS: either use Internet Recovery, pointed out by Allen, or create a bootable installer with a Mac (see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372). You can also create a bootable installer on Windows, but you will probably need additional software. My piece of advice: create an Apple ID and use Internet Recovery, it is a simple procedure and works like a charm.

Comment: Note that you may run into problems when installing old versions of macOS (the reason being that the certiicates they were signed with have expired). Check this answer for a workaround: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/394259/mac-stuck-in-el-capitan-installer-loop-no-packages-were-eligible-for-install/394758#394758 (the answer deals with El Capitan, but you can most probably use the same trick with other macOS installers).