# macOS X El Capitan bootable USB not working

Tags: macos, usb, startup

I have created El Capitan mac OS X bootable USB using TransMac and El Capitan dmg from Apple. When I boot the iMac (2011) and holding option key, the USB doesn't show in boot menu.

1. I have changed the clock to 01010116 but the problem still exist.
2. I have tried this with other sticks (USB 2 and 3) but no luck.
3. I have tried formatting USB with GPT (diskpart) but no luck.

Can someone give me a few hints on how to get El Capitan installation start?

Thanks

Comment: An iMac 2011 should be capable of using Internet Recovery, which might be simpler… or see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142169/how-do-i-create-a-mac-bootable-usb-drive-using-windows

Comment: I use this to make bootable USB installers https://diskmakerx.com/

Comment: Internet recovery doesn't work and I don't know why. I get into Recovery Utilities using Option+Command+R but Reinstall Mac OS X gives me error: Can't download the additional components ...

Comment: @SteveChambers I use Windows to prepare USB stick

Comment: @Sam For Internet Recovery to work, you may need to change the date of your Mac, see my answer at https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/394758/32815 for details.

Comment: @jaume Yes, I did that in previous attempts. I am preparing USB High Sierra using another mac and it looks fine so far. I am waiting for full OS installation to post the outcomes.

Comment: You should put in you question that you have access to another Mac. In this case, your question is a duplicate of the question [How do I create El Capitan installer on a Catalina (or post-El Capitan) installed Mac for use on USB boot installer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379603/how-do-i-create-el-capitan-installer-on-a-catalina-or-post-el-capitan-installe).

Comment: @DavidAnderson  I did not when I posted this question.

Answer (score 2):

I have used another mac to create bootable USB. For some reason I couldn't use TransMac on Windows to make it happen.